# What is the graph coloring problem that Paul Erdős offered $25 to solve circa 1979?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, math-history, coloring

I know that what I am asking is not a mathematics question, but a question ***about*** a mathematics question, so if it is inappropriate and you're thinking to downvote, I would appreciate a comment first, so that I can delete it or change it (I don't have a lot of reputation here).

I heard something about a \$25 prize offered by Paul Erdős for determining the number of colors required for coloring graphene, and I wanted to know what the exact question is, because I thought Erdős didn't spend a lot of money (and \$25 back then was about \$100 now). However, the only thing I could find about it was some text in German, and I tried Google translate but the precise description of the problem is not clear:

> 1979 löste er ein Problem von Paul Erdős über die Färbung von Graphen
>   (von Erdős mit 25 Dollar dotiert). Er benutzte einen Computer, um eine
>   ebene Menge mit 6448 Punkten ohne gleichseitige Dreiecke der Länge 1
>   zu konstruieren, deren zugehöriger Graph (Punkte wurden jeweils
>   verbunden falls Abstand 1) nicht mit drei Farben färbbar war
>   (chromatische Zahl 4), entgegen der Vermutung von Erdös und zu dessen
>   Überraschung.

I searched so many things such as "graphene chromatic number Erdos" and "graphene graph coloring Erdos" and similar searches but absolutely nothing came up!

Comment: The German word `Graphen` means `graphs`, as well as `graphene`. This has nothing to do with carbon bonds!

Comment: See this is why my Google searches gave me bad results!

Answer (score 4):

The apparently refers to a problem inspired by the problem of ["coloring the the plane."](https://books.google.com/books?id=oBlLDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=graph%20coloring%20problem%20erdos%206448%20vertices&source=bl&ots=KEtvqIrAlP&sig=a8rFNhEoxyUxpiBOLs6yM91_TT8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiY6-Opl6reAhXKy1MKHUB6AGQQ6AEwDXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=graph%20coloring%20problem%20erdos%206448%20vertices&f=false)  Let $G_p$ be the graph whose vertices are the points of the plane, and two vertices are adjacent if the difference between them is $1.$  The problem is to compute the chromatic number of $G_p.$

Here is a snippet from the cited source:
[image]

Comment: +1, thank you for finding this! How did you know where to look though? I mean how did you find it? Are there any credible sources saying that he offered $25 for this?

Comment: I googled "graph coloring problem erdos 6448 vertices."

Comment: Interesting that the FIRST result is this exact Stack Exchange question! And now I'm a bit embarrassed, I should have included the number 6448 in the google search. I didn't think that part was important.